# TensorFlow: How can I summary two objects networks for TensorBoard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a class which has method to create network.

```
class DQN:
    def __init__(self, session, input_size, output_size, name):
        .
        .
        .
        self._build_network()

    def _build_network(self, h_size=16, l_rate=0.01):
        with tf.variable_scope(self.net_name):
            self._X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.input_size], name="input_x")
            net = self._X
            net = tf.layers.dense(net, h_size, activation=lambda x: tf.maximum(0.3*x,x))
            net = tf.layers.dense(net, self.output_size) 
            self._Qpred = net

        self._Y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, self.output_size], dtype=tf.float32)

        # Loss function
        with tf.name_scope("loss") as scope:
            self._loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self._Y - self._Qpred))
            self._loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar("loss", self._loss)

        # Learning
        self._train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=l_rate).minimize(self._loss)

    def update(self, x_stack, y_stack, merged_summary):
        return self.session.run(
            [self._loss, self._train, merged_summary],
            feed_dict={
                self._X: x_stack,
                self._Y: y_stack,
            }
        )
```

And have to create two `DQN`instances (separate networks).

```
def main():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        mainDQN = dqn.DQN(sess, input_size, output_size, name="main")
        targetDQN = dqn.DQN(sess, input_size, output_size, name="target")

        merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs/dqn_log")
        writer.add_graph(sess.graph) 
        .
        .
        .
        loss, _, summary = mainDQN.update(x_stack, y_stack, merged_summary)
        writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=episode)
```

What I want to do is to keep track of `mainDQN`'s `loss` function. But with above codes, it occurs an error when calling `update()` .
:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'target/input_x' with dtype float
     [[Node: target/input_x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I think this error is related with `targetDQN`...

But have no idea how to deal with it.

Need your advices, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the issue is related to `targetDQN` object. Basically what happens is that your `merged_summary` is an op which relies both on your main `loss` and on your target `loss`. Therefore when you ask its evaluation it will require the inputs for both `DQN`.

I would suggest to refactor your `update` function this way:

```
def update(self, x_stack, y_stack):
    return self.session.run(
        [self._loss, self._train, self._loss_summary],
        feed_dict={
            self._X: x_stack,
            self._Y: y_stack,
        }
    )
```

so you only ask for the evaluation of the right summary.

EDIT: If you want more summaries associated to one of your `DQN` object, you could merge them using the `tf.summary.merge` method (see the [API documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/merge)) and ask for its evaluation.

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks

Comment: Question: If I add more summary instance variable(say, `self._weight, self._bias`..etc) Do I have to  add those manually in `[self._loss, self._train, self._loss_summary]`? Feel like bad code... Any better way?

Comment: There is a method to do this: `tf.summary.merge` see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/merge